# Karatzas & Shreve, Problem 2.22, Positivity of Stopping Time

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times, filtrations

Problem 2.22 in Karatzas' & Shreve's *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* asks to

> Prove that if $S$ is an optional time and $T$ is a *positive* stopping time with $S \le T$ and $S < T$ on $\{S < \infty\}$, then $\mathcal{F}_{S+} \subset \mathcal{F}_T$.

My **question** is: why is "positive" emphasized in the problem statement, what fails without this assumption? For reference, I'd solve this as follows:

Let $A ∈ \mathcal F_{S+}$. Then for any $t \geq 0$, $A ∩ \{ S < t \} ∈ \mathcal F_t$ by problem 2.21, hence
$$A ∩ \{ T \leq t \} = A ∩ \{ T \leq t \} ∩ \{ S < ∞ \}
= \underbrace{A ∩ \{ S < t \}}_{∈ \mathcal F_t}∩ \underbrace{\{T \le t\}}_{ ∈ \mathcal F_t } ∈ \mathcal F_t, $$
where the first equality uses $S \leq T$, so that $\{ T \le t \} ⊆ \{ S < ∞ \}$, and the second equality uses that $\{ S < ∞ \} ⊆ \{ S < T \}$, so that $\{ T \leq t \} ∩ \{ S < ∞ \} = \{ T \leq t \} ∩ \{ S < t \}$. Since $t \ge 0$ was arbitrary, $A ∈ \mathcal F_T$ follows.

Comment: Congrats. Nice proof and you found a gem by reading very carefully.  Since $S\le T$ it follows that $\{T=0\}\subset\{S=0\}\subset\{S<\infty\}\,.$ By $S<T$ on $\{S<\infty\}$ it follows that $\{T=0\}=\emptyset\,.$ That is: $T$ must be positive.

Comment: @Kurt G., thanks for your response, this answers my question. Do you want to repost it as an answer so I can accept & mark the question as answered?

Comment: Having  a bit of a dilemma because I  believe that future readers of K&S will learn more when they think it through themselves instead of finding the solution in this "manual". Have fun when you continue reading.

Comment: I see, thanks again.